# Как правильно организовать права для docker контейнеров

Tags: linux, docker, permissions

### Есть:

- 2 докер контейнера (nginx, php) и общая директория /var/www

  ```
  version: '2'
  services:
     web:
       image: nginx
       ports:
         - "80:80"
       links:
         - app
       volumes:
         - /var/www:/var/www/html
     app:
       image: php:7-fpm
       volumes:
         - /var/www:/var/www/html
  ```
- проекты добавляю локально в /var/www c правами **myuser:myuser ug+rwx**

### Проблема:

- каждый контейнер использует своего внутренего пользоватя (nginx, www-data)
- все остальные команды в контейнере делаються от root
- постоянные проблемы с "Permission denied"

### Что нужно:

Не перенастраивая каждый контейнер под одного пользователя (root), избавиться от вышеуказаных проблем

### Допонительно:

- Без докера, имея большой зоопарк сервисов, проблема решалась SUID
  меткой, иногда добавленим пользователей в центральную группу. Но этот
  способ с докером "не работает", так как каждый контейнер незнает о
  групах и пользователях извне
- Есть идея что докер может запускать контейнеры (сервисы) от имени нужного мне пользователя, таким образом неразбираясь в дебрях контейнеров они будут редактировать файлы (volumes) от имени пользователя хостовой машины
- На данный момент проблема не решаемая хорошим способом, вот официальная  [дискусия на гитхабе](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7198)

Answer (score 1):

> каждый контейнер использует своего внутренего пользоватя (nginx, www-data)

Это не нужно в контейнере. У вас один процесс на контейнер, вам физически не нужны дополнительные пользователи. Вам не нужно сегрегировать ресурсы, вам не страшно, если пользователь залезет в системные файлы, потому что сломанный контейнер переподнимается за секунду.

За контейнерами кроется очень большая философия, одна из плоскостей которых хорошо отражена в концепции двенадцатифакторного приложения. Когда вы пишете приложение правильно, само приложение не использует файловую систему вообще - логи идут в stdout или сборщик логов, файлы стримятся в файловые хранилища, данные - в базу данных. Если у вас есть проблемы с правами доступа, то вы зачем-то пишете что-то на диск, и делаете это абсолютно зря. Это оправдано, потому что переход на двенадцатифакторное приложение требует хороших таких затрат, но правда остается той же - вам просто физически не нужно ничего писать на диск, иметь несколько пользователей, запускать несколько процессов.

Comment: у меня все кашерно, сервис nginx получил на обработку директорию, и обработывает. Вот только мне не нравиться что сервис делает лишние дейсвтия с директорией в виде изменения свойств файлов. Вопрос больше к менеджеру (програме docker), как заставить контейнеры работать с volume не изменяя свойств файлов, что бы контейнер (сервис) обрабатывал входящие данные от имени пользователя который использует конейнер

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете воспользоваться chmod.

**[chmod](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)** - программа для изменения прав доступа к файлам, директориям.

Команда chmod имеет следующий синтаксис:

```
chmod [options] mode[,mode] file1 [file2 ...]
```

Для примера, приведу несколько кодов, для изменения прав доступа:

> 744 (-rwxr--r--)
>       Каждый пользователь может читать, владелец имеет право редактировать и запускать на выполнение
>
> 755 (-rwxr-xr-x)
>       Каждый пользователь имеет право читать и запускать на выполнение; владелец может редактировать
>
> 777 (-rwxrwxrwx)
>       Каждый пользователь может читать, редактировать и запускать на выполнение

Comment: и как воспользоваться этой командой в указаном мною случае :) Любой контейнер может создать файл с другими правами от имени другого пользователя. Я же не могу каждую минуту запускать chmod -R 777 .

Comment: В таком случае эту задачу нужно решать другим способом. Так как 2 контейнера должны использовать файлы друг друга хорошим решением будет использовать 3-й контейнер к которому, с помощью некоего API,  будут обращаться первые 2. В этом случае не придется бороться с ветрянными мельницами. Как вариант можно воспользоваться samba,ftp, webdav.